# Telerik ASP.Net RadGrid Add New Record Client Side Javascript Prevent Behavior

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

I am attaching an onClick event to the Add Record button on my RadGrid. Code as follows:

Code Behind

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Item is GridCommandItem)
        {
                LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("InitInsertButton");
                lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "testClick()");
        }
}
```

Javascript

```
function testClick(){
    // Perform some Client Side Validation
    var validated = false;

    if(!validated){
        radalert('Validation Fail', 100, 100, 'Window', null, null);

        // What to call here to prevent the RadGrid from going into Insert (Edit) mode?? 
//I tried return false; but that did not prevent the grid.
    }
}
```

So on my JS call, after the alert window has been displayed and I closed it, the RadGrid still goes into edit mode.

I tried a variation of the following:

Code Behind

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
        if(e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName)
        {
                // If Validation Failed, prevent Radgrid from going to Edit Mode.
                RadGrid1..MasterTableView.ClearEditItems();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer so that for everyone who may stumble on this:

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridCommandItem)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("InitInsertButton");
        lnk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return testClick()");
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function testClick(){
    // Perform some Client Side Validation
    var validated = false;

    if(!validated){
        radalert('Validation Fail', 100, 100, 'Window', null, null);
                return false;
    }
}
```